# Pdf viewer in Java applet

Tags: java, applet, pdf-viewer

Hi my company needs a PDF viewer, but not the Acrobat reader or another independent program, it should be in Java applet, where our requirement is to view the PDF file not to copy or paste and the location of the file also should not been shown explicitly, is that any open software library or tool available, I googled but I can't find anything which reaches my requirements.

Comment: Please mention your effort here. If you have not attempted to do, please read documents and refer the web before come here.

Comment: Why here all giving minus for my quetion wahts wrong with that

Comment: People are giving you a minus because this question does not indicate to us that you have put in some effort. The idea is to encourage people to assist others, but only if those others try to help themselves as well. Don't be offended, learn from it - it's great opportunity to make sure your next questions shows everyone you have put in effort and tried your best to find a solution.

Comment: *"our requirement is to view the pdf file not to copy or paste and loction of the file also should not shown explitly"*  If you are trying to limit the user access to the PDF then - shame on you.  I'd just fire up [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/), see where the PDF is being pulled from, then do a direct fetch.  If it is available to your applet, it is probably available by pasting the URL in the address bar and hitting 'enter'.  (Not one of the down-voters.)  BTW - what is the content of the PDF and why is it so sensitive that you're providing it to people that you apparently do not trust?

Answer (score 2):

PDF viewing in an applet is a pain..

Try http://www.jpedal.org/support_tutApplet.php or http://www.snowbound.com/products/document-viewer/applet-demo for some solutions.

You might fare better here if you do some research on your own though.

Comment: I agree with @Ewald. PDF viewer in applet is really a pain.
I have gone throught this pain earlier. :-)

Comment: @JapanTrivedi Indeed, and there's of course the fun fact that so many people block Java applets these days due to security concerns. I think we need to find better ways, or just let the browser handle it.

Comment: @Ewald: As Chrome does - sadly it does not always work due to (I guess) missing fonts at least in some Linux distros.

Comment: @home Correct, there are some issues, but alas, it's less than with applets, if you ask me. I've also had the missing font issues, but it's just gotten better with time.

Comment: @Ewald: Do not missunderstand me - I fully agree. In fact I've set Chrome as default PDF viewer :-)

Comment: @home Exactly what I said :)   Chrome is the better solution, even if there's missing fonts - applets are becoming a real pain...